# Backtracking permuting a list

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to permute a list but I cannot do it, it goes infinite cycle. I tried different things but somehow the only thing that it shows me is 1 2 3 ... 1 2 3 etc

This is the code:

```
def prints(v,k):
    s = ''
    for i in range(k + 1):
        s += str(v[i]) + ' '
    print(s)   

def continuare(v,k):
    ok = True
    for i in range(k):
        if v[i] == v[k]:
            ok = False
            break
    return ok

def back(v,a):
    k = 0
    caut = False
    while k>-1:
        caut = False        
        pos = 0
        while pos < len(a) and caut == False:
                v[k] = a[pos]
                pos += 1
                if continuare(v,k):
                    caut = True
        if caut == False:
            k -= 1
        elif k == len(a) - 1:
            prints(v,k)
        else:
            k += 1


a = [1,2,3]
v = []
for x in range(len(a)):
    v.append(a[0])
back(v,a)
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input with expected output?

Comment: Im expecting the program to permute the list a. Output should be smth like this: 123 132 213 231 312 321

Comment: Do you want all permutations of the list?  Use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: if you can convert this [backtracking example](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) to python :)

Comment: I need to do it using backtracking :)

Comment: I'm generating a combination of 3 numbers that exists in list a. And when they are generated I print them. That's the main idea

Comment: What algorithm are you using?  I recommend starting over with @Shan's suggested example.

Comment: yes, we need algorithm, it is difficult for me to understand code flow.

Comment: @KangJiYoung13, this might be closer to what you want http://pastebin.com/kPGa4eqU based on the c code in the link

Comment: if you want a swap function http://pastebin.com/5RegDC47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trivial Python transcription from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/ :

```
def swap(a, i, j):
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

def permute(a, i, n):
    if i == n:
        print(a)
        return
    for j in range(i, n+1):
        swap(a, i, j)
        permute(a, i+1, n)
        swap(a, i, j)  # backtrack

def main():
    a = list('ABC')
    permute(a, 0, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd rather have `permute` be a generator yielding the permutations, with `main` looping on them and printing them, but this may be closer to the `C` original and thus easier to follow.  Note that one difference is a must: what's being permuted here is a list, not a string as in the C original, because strings are immutable in Python (so `swap` would require substantially different logic, returning the "string with swapped characters" rather than being able to work in-place as the "backtracking" logic requires).

Comment: why is the return necessary?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it's not **necessary** -- you could, instead, nest the `for` loop inside an `else` branch.  However, **flat is better than nested**: getting out of a function (or loop) as soon as you know it's done, rather than nesting substantial code in an `else` branch, is a more Pythonic idiom.